# Why "afraid of" and not "brave of"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adjectives

Recently my preschooler's teacher started teaching kids that they should be "brave of" something and not "afraid of" it. Maybe it is simply because "brave of" is never used, but that syntax strikes me as off. Unfortunately, I can't quite articulate why. So, I would like to know:

1. Is that syntax incorrect?
2. Why is it incorrect/incorrect?

My guess is that the implication of "brave of" is that the item is the *cause* of bravery (thus "brave of the dark" actually means, "brave because of the dark"). Perhaps because "of" can mean "from"?

Comment: *Not afraid of the dark* is the normal phrase precisely because very few people are actually *braver because of the dark*.

Comment: Better would be ***Brave against the dark.***

Comment: I think for ELU this is just General Reference, but if it had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) there might have been more point to it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If that is the case, my apologies. I had thought, perhaps, that this might have been a question of obscure syntax.

Comment: Another option is to use the verb instead: _brave the dark_. This seems close to the teacher's intended meaning.

Comment: "Fearless of" works.

Comment: There is the phrase "brave of heart", perhaps the teacher is vaguely thinking of that?... by the way, "Fearless of" doesn't quite work.  "I am afraid of bees, because they might sting me.", "I am brave of bees, although they might sting me." (I suppose this is how you use it?), "I am fearless about bees, I don't mind being stung."

Answer (score 3):

The two words are used very differently.

- You are afraid **of** something.
- You are brave. (Possibly **despite** something)

So the teacher is incorrect - you can't just be brave **of** something.

Comment: Is it just a matter of common use? Or is there a grammatical rule that I am unaware of?

Comment: At http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch5.html (example 62 ff) is a treatment of 'adjective phrases' . The term 'transitive adjective' may also be used, but is ambiguous (see http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3096 ). At http://www.bedavaingilizce.com/prepositions/adj_pre.htm is a reasonable list of 'adjective + preposition' constructions; 'brave of' isn't listed (though neither are many accepted pairings). I'd say your preschooler's teacher is using the unnatural 'brave of' pairing in a tongue-in-cheek way. This is of dubious merit amongst people learning the basics.

Answer (score 1):

*Afraid of* means *having been caused to have (i.e. possessing) fear of*. "Of" in this case means "resulting from," with the full implication that the entity feared is also the causative agent of the fear. In other words, if we say George is afraid of ghosts, then we are essentially saying that ghosts made George afraid of them.

Thus we can see that "brave of" would not be syntactically equivalent. *Brave* does not mean *having been caused to have bravery*. It means "bold; possessing courage; unafraid." This is not a result of the effect of any outside agency. A ghost cannot make George brave. So I find "brave of" to be grammatically invalid.

Alternatively, I have heard the usage "brave about," as in "George is rather brave about doing things most people wouldn't venture to do." And I believe "about" could be used in place of the "of" suggested in the OP; for example, I think you could say, "George is brave about ghosts," although generally I think people are more comfortable saying "brave about" an action, such as, "brave about going into a haunted house," or "brave about" *some generalization*, such as "brave about anything that has to do with ghosts." Another way of putting it would be "brave when it comes to searching for ghosts." These are just a few examples; there are more.